# Rails 4 - has_many through fetching issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have a many to many association wich is being implemented with rails has_many through shortcut.

My models are called:

1. **Cliente**
2. **StatusTransacaoPagSeguro**
3. **Historico**

They were defined this way:

```
class StatusTransacaoPagSeguro < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :historicos
  has_many :clientes, through: :historicos
end

class Cliente < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :historicos
  has_many :status_transacao_pag_seguros, through: :historicos
end

class Historico < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cliente
  belongs_to :status_transacao_pag_seguro
end
```

I have the following historico record:

```
#<Historico id: 1, cliente_id: 3, status_transacao_pag_seguros_id: 3, created_at: "2014-06-01 19:44:42", updated_at: "2014-06-01 19:44:42">
```

when I run

```
historico.cliente
```

I get the associated 'cliente' record, but when I run

```
historico.status_transacao_pag_seguro
```

I get **nil**.

Where's the problem? I defined the pluralization correctly? Since those names are in Portuguese language I think that there's some problem with it but I don't know how to overcome that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FK for status_transacao_pag_seguro in historicos table is wrong. It should be `status_transacao_pag_seguro_id` (without the `s`). With the following migration you should be good to go:

```
def change
  rename_column :historicos, :status_transacao_pag_seguros_id, :status_transacao_pag_seguro_id
end
```